# Trying to get dots to move away from Pacman in clone

Tags: c#, distance, pacman

Recently, I've been working on a simple Pacman-like game that includes two "Pacmen" and randomly spawning stones for them to eat. I really want to try and get the stones to move away from them every time a Pacman gets near a stone, but I'm not sure exactly how this is done. Could someone perhaps take a look at my code and give me some suggestions? Thank you, I really appreciate it!

Form1 Code file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Media;

namespace EaterGame1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    public static extern long PlaySound(String lpszName, long hModule, long dwFlags);

    private ArrayList Stones = new ArrayList(30);
    private Eater TheEater = new Eater(100, 100);
    private Eater TheOtherEater = new Eater(100, 50);
    private Random RandomGen = new Random();
    private const int NumberOfStones = 100;
    private Score TheScore = new Score(640, 350);
    private Score TheOtherScore = new Score(640, 330);
    private int TheSeconds = 0;
    private TimerDisplay TheTime = new TimerDisplay(7, 350);
    //private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    //private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
    private Thread oThread = null; 




    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeStones();
        InitializeTimer();

        // reduce flicker

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
    }


    private string m_strCurrentSoundFile = "miss.wav";
    public void PlayASound()
    {
        if (m_strCurrentSoundFile.Length > 0)
        {
            //PlaySound(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + m_strCurrentSoundFile, 0, 0);

            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + m_strCurrentSoundFile);
            simpleSound.Play();


        }
        m_strCurrentSoundFile = "";
        oThread.Abort();
    }

    public void PlaySoundInThread(string wavefile)
    {
        m_strCurrentSoundFile = wavefile;
        oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PlayASound));
        oThread.Start();
    }


    public void InitializeTimer()
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    public void InitializeStones()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfStones; i++)
        {
            Stones.Add(new Stone(RandomGen.Next(
                10, ClientRectangle.Right - 10),
                RandomGen.Next(10, ClientRectangle.Bottom - 30)));

        }
    } 




    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {


        string result = e.KeyData.ToString();
        Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
        Invalidate(TheOtherEater.GetFrame());
        switch (result)
        {
            case "Left":
                TheEater.MoveLeft(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "Right":
                TheEater.MoveRight(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "Up":
                TheEater.MoveUp(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "Down":
                TheEater.MoveDown(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "E":
                TheOtherEater.MoveNorthWest(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheOtherEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "Q":
                TheOtherEater.MoveNorthEast(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheOtherEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "C":
                TheOtherEater.MoveSouthWest(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheOtherEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "Z":
                TheOtherEater.MoveSouthEast(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheOtherEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "W":
                TheOtherEater.MoveUp(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheOtherEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "A":
                TheOtherEater.MoveLeft(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheOtherEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "D":
                TheOtherEater.MoveRight(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheOtherEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            case "X":
                TheOtherEater.MoveDown(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheOtherEater.GetFrame());
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

        int hit = CheckIntersection();
        if (hit != -1)
        {
            TheScore.Increment();
            PlaySoundInThread("hit.wav");
            Invalidate(TheScore.GetFrame());
            Invalidate(((Stone)Stones[hit]).GetFrame());
            Stones.RemoveAt(hit);
            if (Stones.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You Win!\nYour time is " + TheTime.TheString + " seconds.\nThe first eater ate " + TheScore + " stones!\nThe second eater ate " + TheOtherScore + " stones!");
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        int hit2 = CheckIntersection2();
        if(hit2 != -1)
        {
            TheOtherScore.Increment();
            PlaySoundInThread("hit.wav");
            Invalidate(TheOtherScore.GetFrame());
            Invalidate(((Stone)Stones[hit2]).GetFrame());
            Stones.RemoveAt(hit2);
            if (Stones.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You Win!\nYour time is " + TheTime.TheString + " seconds.\nThe first eater ate " + TheScore + " stones!\nThe second eater ate " + TheOtherScore + " stones!");
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);


        // draw the score

        TheScore.Draw(g);
        TheOtherScore.Draw(g);

        // draw the time

        TheTime.Draw(g, TheSeconds);


        // draw the stones

        for (int i = 0; i < Stones.Count; i++)
        {
            ((Stone)Stones[i]).Draw(g);
        }

        // also draw the eater
        TheEater.Draw(g);
        TheOtherEater.Draw(g);


    }


    private int CheckIntersection()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Stones.Count; i++)
        {
            Rectangle stoneRect = ((Stone)Stones[i]).GetFrame();
            if (TheEater.GetFrame().IntersectsWith(stoneRect))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private int CheckIntersection2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Stones.Count; i++)
        {
            Rectangle stoneRect = ((Stone)Stones[i]).GetFrame();
            if (TheOtherEater.GetFrame().IntersectsWith(stoneRect))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TheSeconds++;
        Invalidate(TheTime.GetFrame());

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Eater Code file:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace EaterGame1
{
/// <summary>
/// Eats all the dots
/// </summary>
public class Eater
{
    public Point Position;
    static Bitmap EaterImage = null;
    static Bitmap EaterImage2 = null;
    static Bitmap EaterImage3 = null;
    static Bitmap EaterImage4 = null;
    int inc = 3;
    int LastPositionX = 0;
    int LastPositionY = 0;

    public Eater()
    {
        // 
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
        Position.X = 30;
        Position.Y = 35;
        if (EaterImage == null)
        {
            EaterImage = new Bitmap("eater.gif");
        }

        if (EaterImage2 == null)
        {
            EaterImage2 = new Bitmap("eater2.gif");
        }

        if(EaterImage3 == null)
        {
            EaterImage3 = new Bitmap("eater3.gif");
        }

        if (EaterImage4 == null)
        {
            EaterImage4 = new Bitmap("eater4.gif");
        }
    }

    public Eater(int x, int y)
    {
        // 
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
        Position.X = x;
        Position.Y = y;
        if (EaterImage == null)
        {
            EaterImage = new Bitmap("eater.gif");
        }

        if (EaterImage2 == null)
        {
            EaterImage2 = new Bitmap("eater2.gif");
        }

        if (EaterImage3 == null)
        {
            EaterImage3 = new Bitmap("eater3.gif");
        }

        if (EaterImage4 == null)
        {
            EaterImage4 = new Bitmap("eater4.gif");
        }

    }

    public Rectangle GetFrame()
    {
        Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(Position.X, Position.Y, EaterImage.Width, EaterImage.Height);
        return myRect;
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {

        Rectangle destR = new Rectangle(Position.X, Position.Y, EaterImage.Width, EaterImage.Height);
        Rectangle srcR = new Rectangle(0, 0, EaterImage.Width, EaterImage.Height);

        // make it look like the mouth is moving
        if (((Position.X % 2 == 1) && ((Position.X - LastPositionX) != 0)) ||
             ((Position.Y % 2 == 1) && ((Position.Y - LastPositionY) != 0))
           )
            g.DrawImage(EaterImage, destR, srcR, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        else
            g.DrawImage(EaterImage2, destR, srcR, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        if (((Position.X % 2 == 1) && ((Position.X - LastPositionX) != 0)) ||
         ((Position.Y % 2 == 1) && ((Position.Y - LastPositionY) != 0))
       )
            g.DrawImage(EaterImage3, destR, srcR, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        else
            g.DrawImage(EaterImage4, destR, srcR, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        LastPositionX = Position.X;
        LastPositionY = Position.Y;

    }

    public void MoveLeft(Rectangle r)
    {
        if (Position.X <= 0)
            return;  // precondition

        Position.X -= inc;
    }

    public void MoveRight(Rectangle r)
    {
        if (Position.X >= r.Width - EaterImage.Width)
            return;  // precondition

        Position.X += inc;
    }

    public void MoveUp(Rectangle r)
    {
        if (Position.Y <= 0)
            return;  // precondition

        Position.Y -= inc;
    }

    public void MoveDown(Rectangle r)
    {
        if (Position.Y >= r.Height - EaterImage.Height)
            return;  // precondition

        Position.Y += inc;
    }

    public void MoveNorthWest(Rectangle r)
    {
        MoveUp(r);
        MoveRight(r);
    }

    public void MoveNorthEast(Rectangle r)
    {
        MoveUp(r);
        MoveLeft(r);
    }

    public void MoveSouthWest(Rectangle r)
    {
        MoveDown(r);
        MoveRight(r);
    }

    public void MoveSouthEast(Rectangle r)
    {
        MoveDown(r);
        MoveLeft(r);
    }
}
```

}

Stone code file:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace EaterGame1
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Stone.
/// </summary>
public class Stone
{
    public Point Position;
    static Bitmap StoneImage = null;

    public Stone()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
        Position.X = 0;
        Position.Y = 0;
        if (StoneImage == null)
        {
            StoneImage = new Bitmap("stone.gif");
        }
    }

    public Stone(int x, int y)
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
        Position.X = x;
        Position.Y = y;
        if (StoneImage == null)
        {
            StoneImage = new Bitmap("stone.gif");
        }
    }

    public Rectangle GetFrame()
    {
        Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(Position.X, Position.Y, StoneImage.Width, StoneImage.Height);
        return myRect;
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        Rectangle destR = new Rectangle(Position.X, Position.Y, StoneImage.Width, StoneImage.Height);
        Rectangle srcR = new Rectangle(0, 0, StoneImage.Width, StoneImage.Height);
        g.DrawImage(StoneImage, destR, srcR, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Aidian, you need to start using the `Debugger` you can't possibly expect anyone to debug all of what you have posted in your question do you..?

Comment: @MethodMan unfortunately, the debugger would not help at all here. I'm looking for maybe a formula or some way to measure the distance between the pacmen and the stones. I would have debugged, should the problem have warranted a debugging, but nothing's intrinsically wrong with it, it's just not as complex as I want it to be, and I was only looking for some advice!

Comment: @Aidan I couldn't find your main method where you are calling your methods. I assumed it would be the Tick Event. You can create a method and call it in your main method (tick?) that checks the distance between a pacman and a stone for each stone. Then if the stone is closer to the pacman than your acceptable value, get the x and y pos of both the stone and the pacman - check if the pacman is to the north south east west of that stone and move your stone accordingly. Some pseudo code for you.

Comment: Is the movement of the pacman being done only on keypresses? Or by the tick event or some other auto firing even (presummingly 60 times per second aka 60fps)?

Comment: @Radmation The pacman is only moving on keypresses, yes, though I don't think it's 60fps.

Answer (score 0):

I would give stone a method (to be called once a frame) to the effect of:

```
public void Move(Point eater){
    xDif = Position.x - eater.x;
    if(xDif != 0) Position.x += inc*(xDif)/abs(xDif);
    //you will need similar code to address the y
}
```

where inc is whatever speed you want the stones to move at. This algorithm will work for moving open spaces as well closed ones. You will still need code to prevent the stones from entering walls, but sense I don't see any of the code you use for walls, I can't help you there.

Comment: There are not frames. The keypress events are driving the game's "frames". I was confused too.

Comment: You have to take into account the width of the eater and the stone to get the "right_edge" and "left_edge" of each.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new method and place it inside your switch statement in program.cs.

My code isn't perfect but I hope this gets the idea across.

```
switch (result)
        {
            case "Left":
                TheEater.MoveLeft(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                CheckIfEaterIsCloseToMe(); // new method
                break;
            case "Right":
                TheEater.MoveRight(ClientRectangle);
                Invalidate(TheEater.GetFrame());
                break;
```

...

```
private void CheckIfEaterIsCloseToMe()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Stones.Count; i++)
    {
        Rectangle stoneRect = ((Stone)Stones[i]).GetFrame();
        if (TheOtherEater.GetFrame().IsClose(stoneRect, TheOtherEater.GetFrame()))
        {
            // call move method maybe - or just move
        }
    }


}

private bool IsClose(Rectange r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    // check if the r1 is close to r2 -- get the left - right - top - bottom of each rectangle
    // first you need to determine if the other rectangle is on the left or right or top or bottom of this rectangle
    if( ( (r1.X + r1.Width)  - r2.X) <= 20 ) // 20 is threshold -- if on the right -- take the right side minus left side
    {
           // move stone how you want -> maybe to the right more
           return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```